# What even is a Harvest Show?

Tags: love-kome

One recurring element in *Love Kome: We Love Rice* is the idea of a "Harvest Show", which is something that Hinohikari (our protagonist) desperately wants to be a part of. I had previously understood this to be some sort of rice-based performance art, judging from what we'd seen of the [Hinohikari / Akitakomachi 
/ Nikomaru cross-dressing idol unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7mza.jpg). (Yes, if you thought you'd seen everything, come watch *Love Kome* for an idol unit composed of cross-dressing personified rice varieties.)

However, in episode 5, Sasanishiki stops a bullet train from running over a conveniently-placed dog by means of what onlookers (Hinohikari and friends) describe as a "Harvest Show". (It is unclear how creating a few ears of rice helped anything here, but this is anime, so whatever.)

[image: episode 5, 01:46]

An insert song (titled "Fine Dress") does play in the background as he leaps from the roof of the school ([summoning, in the process, a <s>jelly donut</s> rice ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMFyE.jpg)), but he's not actually *singing* it in-show.

So basically I no longer have any idea what a Harvest Show is in this anime.

Comment: It's literally just one if many pun ridden terms referring a performance show by the idol group, H@rve☆star.

Answer (score 2):

The [official site (Japanese)](http://love-kome.com/introduction/) describes it as

> **Harvest Show**
> It is a live performance for the grains to appeal for their deliciousness to the surroundings.

which is basically the same as what [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34402/Love_Kome__We_Love_Rice) and [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=18890) describes

> [...] to perform at the "Harvest Show" to show the delicious appeal of rice grains.

How or what do they do, don't ask me... but in addition to its comedy genre, **the show is full of parodies**.

---

Sasashiniki stopping a bullet train from hitting a dog in episode 5 is actually a parody of *Kinnikuman* about Terryman stopping a bullet train... from hitting a puppy. [Wikia](http://kinnikuman.wikia.com/wiki/Terryman) stated,

> In the 21st Olympics, he (Terryman) made it to the third preliminary round, shoving bullet trains, but was disqualified for *stopping his train from hitting a puppy* (touching the train twice resulted in a disqualification)
>
> [image: Terryman stopping a bullet train from hitting a puppy]
>
> <sup>[Image source](http://blog.livedoor.jp/conbul/archives/52054019.html)</sup>

Reference: [ほかこ's Hatena Blog (Japanese)](http://umekox.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/05/05/113000)

---

The cross-dressing idol unit in episode 3 is certainly a parody of many idol units (as seen in the naming proposal): *iM@S* (maiM@S), PriPara's *SoLaMi♡SMILE* (KoMeMi☆SMILE), *Aikatsu!* (MaiKatsu), *Love Live!* (Love Rice), etc.

[image: naming proposal]